# Random JSON object generator

Tags: javascript, json

I need a tool which generates random JSON objects. I want to use this tool to do testing on my HTTP POST requests and use the random JSON object in it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What platform are you developing with?  ASP.NET?  Java?  PHP? :-)

Comment: I create one simple tool check [this](https://avhishek05.github.io/json-generator/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would recommend just building a script in PHP...its really easy to convert arrays to json, so you could just make a randomized array and do:  `echo json_encode($array);`

Answer (score 9):

Check out this service: http://json-generator.appspot.com/
It supports several functions:

- int **$incr** (increment, starting from 1)
- int **$randInt(a,b)** (random integer from a to b)
- boolean **$bool** (random true/false)
- string **$firstName**/**$lastName** (random (1 of 100) russian name/surname)
- string **$company** (random company name 1 of 100)
- string **$phone** (random russian phone number)
- string **$email** (random email, generated base on $name and $company)
- string **$date** (random data)
- **$repeat:n** repeats object n times in array

original post in russian: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/132286/

Comment: This is a really awesome program, but is limited by not being open source. It would be really nice to embed it in some test code.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look at [mockJSON](http://experiments.mennovanslooten.nl/2010/mockjson/), whose approach is similiar to the appspot json-generator but is [open source](https://github.com/mennovanslooten/mockJSON).

Here are the keywords it supports.

- @NUMBER
- @LETTER_UPPER
- @LETTER_LOWER
- @MALE_FIRST_NAME
- @FEMALE_FIRST_NAME
- @LAST_NAME
- @EMAIL
- @DATE_YYYY
- @DATE_DD
- @DATE_MM
- @TIME_HH
- @TIME_MM
- @TIME_SS
- @LOREM
- @LOREM_IPSUM

If you wanted to use templating with Python you might want to look into the port I created at https://github.com/JamesMcMahon/mockjson.py.

Answer (score 2):

Try this awesome tool: [Json Generator](http://www.json-generator.com/). You need nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I made a tool based on [mockJSON](http://experiments.mennovanslooten.nl/2010/mockjson/) that lets you `POST` requests to get the templated JSON, instead of using a local plugin. You can check it [out here](http://jsongen.herokuapp.com/).